# sharing microsoft word file?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

Is there a way to share a word file amongst user, just like google docs? I am tired of using google docs because when I port it to ms word the layouts are all messed up. I want to be able to make updates to a particular word file.

Answer (score 1):

There was [Microsoft Office Live](http://www.officelive.com/en-us/), as another person has pointed out, but it is about to close.  One of my Office Live accounts has already been migrated to SkyDrive, which replaces it.

If you have a Live ID or Hotmail address (same thing really), sign into Hotmail and go to the 'Office' tab at the top.  This is your [SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/), where you can keep your Office documents online and also share them with other people with Live IDs.  you can alternatively out the files in the Public folder (or any other folder you make public), where anyone can access them.

Office 2010 can save files directly to SkyDrive and I think there is an add-on to do the same in Office 2007 apps.

Another cool thing is that they do not even need Office installed, as the files can be opened in the new [Office Web Apps](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/).

[This is an example](http://goo.gl/FmDl) of a file I have made public on SkyDrive.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Microsoft Live option mentioned by others, there's also Micrsoft Groove, which is a set of client-server software an organization can use to have centrally managed security, better integration into the Word program itself, allow multiple users to work on the same document at the same time in a similar manner to google docs, and also edit offline and sync changes back later.

Comment: That has been replaced by SharePoint.

Comment: hmm... checking again it looks like they just renamed it for Office 2010.